# The tags (bookmarks) and (saves) on meta - synonyms or not?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management, meta

Recently the functionality for bookmarks was completely overhauled and they are now called saves: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019). It is expected that eventually there will be some questions about saves here on meta - we had quite a lot of questions about bookmarks too.

I think that it is reasonable to have a tag which makes them easy to locate. For this reason I have recently created the tag [saves](/questions/tagged/saves). (Of course, a possible outcome of this discussion might be that we don't want this tag - if that's the case, we can simply remove it.)

At the same time, there is a tag called [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks). (Which has [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites) as a synonym - this was the older name for this feature.)

**The main question.** Should the tag [saves](/questions/tagged/saves) and [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) be synonyms?

Comment: I will mention that my personal opinion is that they should **not** be synonyms. Many things work differently for bookmarks and for saves. People searching for advice on saves might try to search using tags and arrive at some posts tagged bookmarks - with obsolete information, which might lead to confusion. (But I'll wait and see what other people think - if nobody else responds, I might try to elaborate this in an answer rather than just in a comment.)

Comment: Regardless of the question whether the tags should be kept separate, it still could make sense to update information in some of the existing posts about bookmarks. (For example, it wasn't possible to bookmark an answer - but saves work for answers, too.)

Comment: I will add a link to [a few messages in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/the-tag-saves-and-bookmarks). (I posted this question following the advice given by a mod in the Tagging chatroom.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Do not make [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) a synonym of [saves](/questions/tagged/saves)

The "saves" feature is quite different from the "bookmarks" feature. Notably, we can save answers, we can organize our saves into custom lists, and one's saved posts are not publicly visible — these are significant changes to the bookmarks feature. (In contrast, the renaming of favorites to bookmarks was just that, a renaming.) Synonymizing the tags could cause confusion, since older, popular posts about bookmarks would show up when a user searches for information regarding saves, and it could be unclear which parts are up-to-date. Even figuring out which of these posts deserve to be updated, and in what manner, would be a significant investment of time and effort.

Instead, better to simply update the tag wiki for [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) to indicate that the feature has been superseded by "Saves", and point to the [saves](/questions/tagged/saves) tag.

Comment: "and one's saved posts are not publicly visible" - I would like at least the option to make them public, to show other users the more useful or interesting posts in my view. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382569

Comment: Voting suggests that this is the preferred option  - and nobody raise any objections - so I accepted this answer.